# gVim on Windows not distinguishing Numpad Enter

Tags: key-bindings, gvim, microsoft-windows

Using gVim on Windows, I'm trying to add a mapping to `<kEnter>`, but it seems that it's not being treated seperately from `<CR>`. New to Windows, so I thought this may just be an OS thing, but I logged some JS key events in Chrome and the  two keys are treated seperately there so... Do I need to configure gVim somehow to recognize those as separate?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: This is not a question, but a bug to report. I can confirm `<kEnter>` is never seen under recent gVim/Win. Neovim-qt/Win works as expected.